# Function are not responding

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

```
function onPlayerReady(event)
{
    event.target.cueVideoById({
        videoId: videos[index].vid,
        startSeconds: videos[index].startSeconds,
        endSeconds: videos[index].endSeconds,
        suggestedQuality: videos[index].suggestedQuality
    });
    
    event.target.playVideo();
    
    console.log('++++++++++++++++++++');
    console.log(player.getVolume());
    console.log(player.getDuration());
    console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
    console.log('++++++++++++++++++++');
}
```

---

and here is the output

---

> ++++++++++++++++++++
>
> undefined
>
> undefined
>
> undefined
>
> ++++++++++++++++++++

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why these player.function () are throwing undefined ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer

These function works when the player is in the state of playing, else won't work

if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {

```
            console.log(player.getVolume());
            console.log(player.getDuration());
            console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
```

}